# How do I check if System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction has an active transaction?

Tags: c#

I have a method which I use to execute all my SQL queries (inserts, updates, delete) and I want to put a check in to make sure the change is within a transaction before the code is executed but I can't find a property against the `SqlTransaction` to check for.

How should I proceed?

Note: I am using `FDBConnection.BeginTransaction("MY_TRANS");` to begin the transaction and standard rollback and commnit methods

Using .NET 4.0 with VS 2010 Web Dev Express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your db is SQL server, @@TRANCOUNT shows # of active transactions in the connection in context

```
Select @@TRANCOUNT
```

if other db , please specify

HTH

Comment: Thanks for that; didn't think of actually running a statement. Sigh. Only been at work for 2 hours and already a long day :)

Comment: Indeed this is the way. Thanks a lot!